# How do I filter arrays of an array by row length using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

How do I filter arrays of an array by row length?

For example, if I had an array such as:

[['A','B','C'],['D','E'],['F','G','H']]

How do I filter by row length of three so that I get this result:

[['A','B','C'],['F','G','H']]

This is just as example, I have thousands of rows to filter through based upon the row length.

Comment: `arr.filter(subArr => subArr.length == desiredLength)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter it

```js
let arr = [['A','B','C'],['D','E'],['F','G','H']];

let result = arr.filter(({ length }) => length === arr.length);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It appears that I can reassign let. This seems to be what I am looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
let arr = [['A','B','C'],['D','E'],['F','G','H']];
let newArr = arr.filter(x => {
    return x.length === 3;
})
```

Please look at the array functions. They are pretty straight forward.

Comment: I think the lhe lambda could be simplified to `x => x.length === 3`